# grep: color different parts of output

Tags: bash, colors, grep

I'm trying to output some text from grep and highlight in different colors.
This is my data:

```
    - name: the name
      displayName: "[JIRA REF] the name"
      description: JIRA REF
      exemptionCategory: waiver
      expiresOn: 2024-03-02T00:00:00Z
      policyDefinitionReferenceIds:
        - REFid
      scope: null
```

I need each key (name, displayName etc) in blue and `JIRA REF` in red

I've managed to isolate it so the key is one color, but when I add in a secondary condition it only matches that
eg

```bash
grep -A3 -B4 -P 2024-03-02 --color=auto file.txt \
| grep --color=auto -P \
'expiresOn|displayName|name|exemptionCategory|policyDefinitionReferenceIds|scope|description' \ 
-A3 -B4
```

will output each key in red, but when I add in

```bash
grep -A3 -B4 -P 2024-03-02 --color=auto file.txt \
| grep --color=auto -P \
'expiresOn|displayName|name|exemptionCategory|policyDefinitionReferenceIds|scope|description' \ 
-A3 -B4 \
| GREP_COLOR='mt=01;31' grep --color=auto -P '.{0,0}JIRA.{0,4}' \
-A3 -B4
```

only the JIRA REF is colored

Comment: "each key" is a logical concept. You might want to use a (YAML) parser that understands what a key is, so you don't have to provide a comprehensive list of names.

Comment: The solution of least effort would be changing `--color=auto` to `--color=always` to make the coloring persist the subsequent piping. Thus, change it for all `grep`s that are followed by a pipe (all but the last in this case, but it won't hurt the last if you'd do it for all of them).

Comment: This is actually very close, however it's persisting the red color even though I'm overriding it with `GREP_COLOR='mt=01;31'`

Comment: Mind your spelling, it's `GREP_COLORS` with an `S` at the end. Also, change `31` to something else to see different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An unoptimized "least effort" solution

While there are better solutions elsewhere on this page, this post (going with my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78101899/grep-color-different-parts-of-output#comment137690228_78101899) to provide actual code) focuses on your current approach (using multiple `grep`s, sequentially piped into one another) to highlight what went wrong, and how to fix it for a "least effort" solution.

```bash
GREP_COLORS='mt=01;35' grep --color=always -A3 -B4 -P '2024-03-02' file.txt |
GREP_COLORS='mt=01;34' grep --color=always -A3 -B4 -P 'expiresOn|displayName|name|exemptionCategory|policyDefinitionReferenceIds|scope|description' |
GREP_COLORS='mt=01;31' grep --color=always -A3 -B4 -P '.{0,0}JIRA.{0,4}'
#         ^        ^^               ^^^^^^
#     spelling    color         coloring mode
```

Apart from some uniform formatting to improve readability, the following changes were applied:

- `GREP_COLORS` is spelled with an `S` at the end
- Setting different colors for each line, including `34` for blue, and leaving `31` for red
- Changing `--color=auto` to `--color=always` as with `auto`, coloring is only enabled for printing, but disabled when piping into another process. (Thus, the last `grep` doesn't actually need to be modified for this use-case, but I included it anyway for consistency and potentially needed interoperability.)

Comment: Thank you! Updated to have this at the end to deal with variable JIRA ticket length
`'JIRA.[0-9]{4,5}'`

Comment: @martyzee You're welcome! As for the regular expression, keep in mind that `.` matches any character. Escape it to only match the dot.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`, this looks convoluted.

What I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

blue=$(tput setaf 4)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
reset=$(tput sgr0)

cat<<EOF | sed -e "s/.*/$blue&$reset/g" -e "s/\[JIRA REF\]/$red\[JIRA REF\]$blue/g"
    - name: the name
      displayName: "[JIRA REF] the name"
      description: JIRA REF
      exemptionCategory: waiver
      expiresOn: 2024-03-02T00:00:00Z
      policyDefinitionReferenceIds:
        - REFid
      scope: null
EOF
```

Feel free to improve to fit exactly your needs. You have more than a starter script :)

[image]

Comment: Almost there, however just needing the key in blue, the rest of the text in "white" and the JIRA REF (which is dynamic as it's a ticket number) in red  
eg it could be something like ABC-1234 and need all of that in red

Answer (score 1):

I would use something more flexible than grep, e.g. sed:

`sed -e 's/displayName: "[[]\([^]]*\)/displayName: "[\x1b[32m\1\x1b[0m/g' -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]*:\)/\x1b[31m\1\x1b[0m/g'  file.txt`

It makes use of the ANSI color escapes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) of VT100 compatible terminal like grep also should.

Comment: Almost there, however just needing the JIRA REF (which is dynamic as it's a ticket number) in red
eg it could be something like ABC-1234 and need all of that in red

Comment: how is it identified? is it the text JIRA REF after the description: or the [JIRA REF] in the displayName?

Comment: assuming the latter, try the edited answer

Comment: it would look like this  
`displayName: "[ABC-1234] the name"`
      `description: ABC-1234`

Where ABC could be anything alpha, and 1234 could be numeric, 4 or 5 chars

Comment: This works great, how can I update the regex to color the whole line?

Comment: in sed, a whole line would be matched by `sed 's/^.*$/\x1b[<colorcode>m\1\x1b[0m/g'`